# Saving nested array of objects to JSON

Tags: json, objective-c

I have an array of nested objects that I want to save as JSON. Object is defined as following:

```
@interface TreeNode : NSObject

@property(nonatomic, strong) NSString *title;
@property(nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray<TreeNode *> *children;
@property(nonatomic, strong) NSString *identifier;
@property(nonatomic, assign) bool isCompleted;

- (instancetype)initWithValue:(NSString *)title :(NSString *)number;
- (void)addChild:(TreeNode *)child;

@end

@implementation TreeNode

- (instancetype)initWithValue:(NSString *)title :(NSString *)number {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        _isCompleted = false;
        _title = [title copy];
        _identifier = [number copy];
        _children = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)addChild:(TreeNode *)child {
    [_children addObject:child];
}

- (void)dealloc
{
    [_title release];
    [_identifier release];
    [_children release];
    
    [super dealloc];
}

@end
```

The above object is added to array as unlimited nested objects as following:
[[String,[[String,[]], [String,[]]]],[String,[]],[String,[]]]
[String,[]] above represents my class object(TreeNode).
I want to save it locally in document directory. I am trying to save it as JSON but not able to convert it to JSON object.

Comment: Show your attempts to convert to/from JSON.

Comment: As a side note, 1. Why are you using MRC instead of ARC? 2. You declare the `title` and `identifier` properties as `strong` but your `init` method is using copy semantics on both.

Comment: It is actually some task I am doing to learn manual memory management as I have possibility to work on a project which is using manual memory management. I have not seen the code yet so I don't know how easy or difficult it will be to convert it to ARC. The app was crashing a lot with title variable but once I did a copy on this, it has fixed the crashes.

Comment: I am getting value for title at init so wouldn't copy will make more sense here than strong?

Comment: Using `copy` in the `NSString` passed to `init` is a good idea. But this means you should declare the `title` and `identifier` properties as `copy` instead of `strong`. And way back before ARC, there was no `strong`. Instead, you used `retain`. With ARC they are now synonyms. But back to your question - please update your question with your attempt JSON code.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, I will follow it. I am now able to save it to JSON file, adding my code as answer to this question.

Answer (score 0):

I am able to save the array as folowing:

```
    -(void) saveToDoList:(NSMutableArray<TreeNode *> *)todoList {
    NSMutableArray *array = [self convertArrayToJson:todoList];
    NSError *error;
    NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:array options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:&error];
    NSString *jsonString = [[[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] autorelease];
    [self writeStringToFile:jsonString];
}
//Following function will convert a nested array of array to JSON Object
-(NSMutableArray *) convertArrayToJson: (NSMutableArray *) array {
    NSMutableArray *mainArray = [NSMutableArray new];
    
    for (TreeNode *element in array) {
        NSMutableDictionary *node = [NSMutableDictionary new];
        [node setValue:element.title forKey:keyTitle];
        [node setValue:element.identifier forKey:keyIdentifier];
        
        if (element.children != nil && [[element children] count] > 0) {
            NSMutableArray *array1 = [self convertArrayToJson:element.children];
            [node setValue:array1 forKey:keyChildren];
        } else {
            [node setValue:nil forKey:keyChildren];
        }
        [mainArray addObject:node];
    }
    return mainArray;
}

- (void)writeStringToFile:(NSString*)aString {
    NSString *fileAtPath = [self jsonFilePath];
    if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:fileAtPath]) {
        [[NSFileManager defaultManager] createFileAtPath:fileAtPath contents:nil attributes:nil];
    }
    [[aString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] writeToFile:fileAtPath atomically:NO];
}
```